# When saving an ASCII grid as a GeoTIFF in QGIS, the resulting raster has slightly different cell values than the input file

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-conversion, esri-ascii-raster, cell-size

My input raster is a Arc ASCII grid that I drag into QGIS.  It has a cell size of 1.  If I try to convert that to a GeoTIFF by going Export>Save as>  GeoTIFF, and using the same extent and cell size of 1 the result looks good.  But when I identify the values within the grid I do not get the exact same number for the GeoTIFF as for the ASCII grid cell values.  When I look at the properties of both layers the Mean, STDDEV etc is exactly the same so I'm confused why the cell values are slightly off. [image]

Comment: When you converted the file did you retain the same CRS? If you projected the file at the same time then you will get changes due to resampling

Comment: Can you share some small asc file for testing?